# Payment Gateway URL - Preferred Name

Tags: ssl, subdomain, domain-name

I'm setting up a payment gateway that will be used on several similar websites and therefore wanted to use one domain name or subdomain to handle all these payments.

From reading I believe there is no difference between using a domainname or a subdomain (correct me if I'm wrong) so I think I will go for a subdomain of the domain that belongs to the overall business.

I'm now trying to decide the preferred subdomain name to use - does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

```
secure.domainname.com
gateway.domainname.com
payment.domainname.com
```

Will be buying an SSL next so need to make a decision.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

secure.domainname.com
 is a good name :)

This is just from other sites I have seen around.